# Help identifying a custom Arduino Uno PCB with three 74LS157N ICs

Tags: pcb-design

I recently came across a custom PCB that appears to be based on the Arduino Uno form factor, but it does not have the typical ATmega328P microcontroller on it. Instead, it has three 74LS157N quad 2-to-1 multiplexer ICs installed. I'm trying to understand the purpose and functionality of this custom board and how it might relate to a GRBL-based CNC system.

Has anyone seen a similar board or have any ideas about what this custom PCB might be used for? Any information or suggestions about the design or possible applications would be greatly appreciated. If possible, please share any relevant schematics, layouts, or project documentation that could help me understand this custom PCB better.

Thank you!

Comment: The schematic (or at least the complete board layout, including all traces) would be helpful.

Comment: If you it is a cnc device, my best guess would be that the shift registers are there to control the many I/O pins on such a device

Answer (score 0):

A single 2-to-1 multiplexer can be connected so that it implements other logic gates like AND, OR, or NOT; see the [SN74LVC1G97](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G97) datasheet for details.

So that board might implement some custom logic. (Or simply a bunch of multiplexers.)